# Secret Reception

Tags: pattern, password

> I think I just came upon a secret reception. I was just about to go in when a guard stopped me and asked for my number. I wasn't sure how the system worked but I was able to see the checklist of attendants. One code number was missing and I used it. Basically the checklist was like this;[image]
>   **Do you know what my attendant code is?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your code was

> 258

The three numbers at the top of each box are the codes for the checklist, as shown by your missing numbers replaced with ?s.
Underneath each code is a blank keypad shape with the numbers 1, 2, and 3

> These represent the first, second, and third keys pressed on a keypad. The keypad looks like this:
>  1 2 3
>  4 5 6
>  7 8 9
>  we know the numbers on the keypad from looking at the other attendant codes, 2 is the first number pressed in 249, 5 is the first number pressed in 573, and 8 is the first number pressed in 819.

Comment: I mean I was expecting a fast answer but I guess that was like taking candy from a baby. I can't even mark it as an answer because of 2 minutes limit. Good job.

Comment: @KeithN is the 4th image supposed to be 849? Or am I misunderstanding the pattern?

Comment: @RyanSmith I corrected it. Thank you.